# mapbox fit bounds to country

Tags: javascript, mapbox

i just want fit my map to my country. I saw some example from https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/ and it's fit to whole Kenya. It's a simple code but i don't know why this function takes two lat and longs. I just google it for what is Keyna lat and long? it's 1.2667° S, 36.8000° E. Why this is different than google's result.

```
function fit() {
    map.fitBounds([[
        32.958984,
        -5.353521
    ], [
        43.50585,
        5.615985
    ]]);
}
```

How to fit to my specific area just like this.

Comment: It takes two lat longs, one for the top left, one for the bottom right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i search for the bounding box of Kenya, i find the following:

http://isithackday.com/geoplanet-explorer/index.php?woeid=23424863

Using those coordinates, it's looks ok:

```
map.fitBounds([
    [-4.71712, 33.90884], // Northeast
    [4.62933, 41.899059]  // Southwest
]);
```

Example using Leaflet on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yRuTxjmQxcoqkVyFbE4q?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

.fitBounds takes two latlng arguments, one for the upper-left corner of the mapview and one for the lower-right corner.

If you would like to just center the map on Kenya, you could use:

```
map.flyTo({center: [Lat, Lng]})
```

Comment: how to know my left corner and lower right corner of my area?

Comment: You're going to have to figure that out.... Use Google Maps and click on the map to get coordinates for a specific point.

Comment: A lot of bounds data here https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540. The one that worked best for me is the run-in literal object

Answer (score 2):

I also was looking for the answer on this question. Leaflet, for example, has a property of a layer to get its bounds (e.g.,`map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());`). Mapbox GL doesn't have anything like that. At least not that I know. To handle this you may access the first and the last coordinates of the currently selected feature: `map.fitBounds([feature.geometry.coordinates[0], feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length-1]])`.

Here is the whole piece of code in case you want to have a popup with a Zoom button on it:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    map.featuresAt(e.point, {layer: 'route-lines', radius: 10, includeGeometry: true}, function (err, features) {
        if (err || !features.length)
            return;

        var feature=features[0];

        new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setHTML(popupTemplate)
            .addTo(map);

        var buttonZoomFeature = document.getElementById('button-zoom');
        buttonZoomFeature.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                map.fitBounds([feature.geometry.coordinates[0], feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length-1]]);
        });

    });
});

var popupTemplate = '<div id="popup-div">\
        <button id="button-zoom" class="button-zoom" type="button">Zoom to</button>\
        </br>\
        </div>';
```

PS. This approach works fine when the layer is a number of lines (roads, for example). If you want to fit the bounds to a country, which is a polygon, you may try taking the first longitude-latitude point as the one that has min latitude and for the second point the one that has max longitude. Or something like that. Just try to play around with this approach. I am sure it will work out.